# Display an Index of Admin Users in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've completed the Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial (for Rails 3) and I am wondering how you would go about displaying all the users that have been assigned the Admin attribute but on a separate page as it doesn't mention this anywhere.

**users_controller.rb**

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,   :only => :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to University Sports!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @title = "Edit user"
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  def admins
    @users = User.admins
    render "users/index"
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end  

  private

    def authenticate
      deny_access unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
FinalProject::Application.routes.draw do
  get "club/new"

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :users do
    collection do
      get :admins
    end
  end

  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  get "sessions/new"

  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

  match '/sign_up', :to => 'pages#sign_up'

  root :to => 'pages#home'

  resources :users
  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

    has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :following, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed   
    has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "followed_id", :class_name => "Relationship", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower

    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

    validates :name,    :presence   => true, :length  => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :email,   :presence   => true, :format  => { :with => email_regex }, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

    scope :admins, where(:admin => true)

    # Automatically create the virtual attribute 'password_confirmation'.
    validates :password, :presence  => true, :confirmation  => true, :length  => { :within => 6..40 }
        before_save :encrypt_password

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil  if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
    user = find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
  end

  def following?(followed)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(followed)
  end

  def follow!(followed)
    relationships.create!(:followed_id => followed.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(followed)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(followed).destroy
  end

  def feed
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
  end

  private

    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt unless has_password?(password)
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
      secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end



end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
UsersController

def admins
   @admins=User.where(:admin => true)
end
```

And add this to your routes file:

```
 resources :users do
    collection do
      get :admins
    end
 end
```

And then just render the @admins instance variable in the admins.html.erb view (which youll have you create in the User views).

Comment: I've tried this, but it comes up with an error "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show" and the application trace says "app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in 'show'"

I've tried updating the def show to the following

`def show`
`@user = User.find(params[:id])`
`@microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])`
`@title = @user.name`
`@admins = User.find(params[:id])`
`end`

Comment: The best way to go about working on ActiveRecord is to use the rails console to get instantaneous feedback on your queries. Try 'admins=User.where(:admin => "true") and youll get an array of all objects that match your criteria. As for your admins instance variable, it should be @admins=User.where(:admin => true) not @admins = User.find(params[:id])

Answer (score 2):

First, you would need to create a route in your `config/routes.rb` file that would route to an action that would display this information. Something like this:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :admins
  end
end
```

That would route to the `admins` action inside the `UsersController`, and so that's what you'll need to define next. It would go like this:

```
def admins
  @users = User.admins
  render "users/index"
end
```

Because the list of admins shouldn't be too different from the users list, you can just assign all the admins to `@users` and then render the `users/index` template... if it exists. I'm probably assuming too much here, but it's one way of doing it.

Now, there's no `admins` method on your `User` class and so you'll need to define that. One way to do that is with a scope, like this:

```
scope :admins, where(:admin => true)
```

This will define the `admins` method on the `User` class, returning a scope of all users who are admins. Scopes are cool, you should look into what else they can do.

Alternatively, you can define a class method:

```
def self.admins
  where(:admin => true)
end
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, I've done everything that you've recommended above and I do have the file index.html.erb in app/views/users. I've tried adding <%= render @admins %> but it produced a NoMethodError in Users#index so I removed it.

Comment: Why would you put `<%= render @admins %>`? You're assigning it to the @users variable and referencing your existing Users#index template. You should be able to call /users/admins and just have it work.